# URL in Facebook post adds extra "www."

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink

I recently created a facebook page for an app our company is developing - https://www.trackdapp.com. However, whenever the owner posts the link on Facebook's mobile app as  [www.trackdapp.com](http://www.trackdapp.com), the link sends people to https://www.www.trackdapp.com.

I understand the simple solutions is to drop the www. prefix and have suggested this to the owner, but I would appreciate any help/suggestions as to why this is happening.

Comment: So if someone posts `www.trackdapp.com` facebook liks to `www.trackdapp.com`? What is the problem?

Comment: no if someone posts www.trackdapp.com facebook links to www.www.trackdapp.com